# Centralized DB For EU Projects' Publications & Deliverables

Tags: publications, repository, eu

A lot of times I face a difficulty in finding the public deliverables and/or publications lists of EU FP6 and even EU FP7 projects.
Usually, these are hosted on the respective projects' websites.
Lately, I've been finding sites that don't list them or are down because of misconfigurations, expired leases, etc.
I've found that repositories such as Cordis et al. usually only host flyers, awards, and posters for example, but no deliverables & no bibliography.

I would like to avoid the brute-force methods of:

- Tracking down the publications lists for each PI assigned to this project for the time span of the project and sifting through it for project-specific publications.
- Tracking down the PI's and mailing each until I receive responses with parts of bibliographies and possibly even some of the public deliverables.

My question, in two parts, is as follows:

1. Is there a centralised database that hosts public deliverables and publications lists for EU FP projects?
2. If not, are you aware of any method other than the above (time-consuming) brute-force techniques?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EU funded a project termed "The OpenAIRE2020 Project" specifically to address the kind of issues I describe above.

> "50 partners, from all EU countries, and beyond, will collaborate to work on this large-scale initiative that aims to promote open scholarship and substantially improve the discoverability and reusability of research publications and data. The initiative brings together professionals from research libraries, open scholarship organisations, national e-Infrastructure and data experts, IT and legal researchers, showcasing the truly collaborative nature of this pan-European endeavor. A network of people, represented by the National Open Access Desks (NOADs), will organise activities to collect H2020 project outputs, and support research data management. Backing this vast outreach, is the OpenAIRE platform, the technical infrastructure that is vital for pulling together and interconnecting the large-scale collections of research outputs across Europe. The project will create workflows and services on top of this valuable repository content, which will enable an interoperable network of repositories (via the adoption of common guidelines), and easy upload into an all-purpose repository (via Zenodo).
>
> OpenAIRE2020 will assist in monitoring H2020 research outputs and will be a key infrastructure for reporting H2020’s scientific publications as it will be loosely coupled to the EC’s IT backend systems. The EC’s Research Data Pilot will be supported through European-wide outreachfor best research data management practices and Zenodo, which will provide long-tail data storage. Other activities include: collaboration with national funders to reinforce the infrastructure’s research analytic services; an APC Gold OA pilot for FP7 publications with collaboration from LIBER; novel methods of review and scientific publishing withthe involvement of hypotheses.org; a study and a pilot on scientific indicators related to open access with CWTS’s assistance; legal studies to investigate data privacy issues relevant to the Open Data Pilot; international alignment with related networks elsewhere with the involvement of COAR."

You can search by project name [here](https://www.openaire.eu/search/find?keyword=). The publication list, project duration, participants and other information related to projects is accessible this way. I'm not sure if the information is comprehensive.

It appears that the OpenAIRE site also stores information from other funding agencies such as the [NSF](https://www.openaire.eu/search/browse/publications?funder=nsf_________::NSF) and the [Australian Research Council](https://www.openaire.eu/search/browse/publications?funder=arc_________::ARC) and provides a tonne of functionality beyond what I mention above (search by doctorate thesis, open access, language etc.).

I've found deliverables listed under [reports](https://www.openaire.eu/search/browse/publications?funder=ec__________::EC&language=eng&type=0017). However, I can't find the deliverables of certain projects I am interested in, so the same may apply to you as well.

As far as I am concerned, I've answered my own question and I'm sharing what I've found with you.
I'll leave the bounty and the question up for another 3-4 days in case anyone else has a better response to add.

Cheers!